# Using includes in `has_many through` relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models. I'm trying to get all of the users assigned to the title list by doing an include.

The query that is returned doesn't include the users only the title list.  What don't I understand?

Query:

```
TitleList.all(:users).where(:id => 43)
```

Models:

```
class Relationship::TitleListUserRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'tbl_title_list_to_users'
  belongs_to :title_list, :foreign_key => 'title_list_id', :class_name => 'TitleList'
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id', :class_name => 'User'
end

class TitleList < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'tbl_title_lists'
  has_many :user_relationships, class_name: 'Relationship::TitleListUserRelationship'
  has_many :users, class_name: 'User', through: :user_relationships, source: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :title_list_relationships, class_name: 'Relationship::TitleListUserRelationship'
  has_many :title_lists, through: :title_list_relationships
end
```

Comment: Is that syntax right?  `TitleList.all(:legacy_titles).where(:id => 43)`.  Probably a typo, I think it would throw an error - what is `:legacy_titles` ?

Comment: Sorry it should be :users.  Edited.

Comment: Are you trying to get all title_lists where the user_id is 43?  Or one title_list whose id is 43 and all its users?

Comment: One title_list whose id is 43 and all its users

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "include" when you say the TitleList should include the user? Because I'm afraid you mean something different then mosts rails programmers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the syntax you used. If what you're looking for is all the users that are related to `TitleList` with id 43, you may write something like:

```
User.joins(user_relationships: :title_list).where(title_lists: {id: 43})
```

or simply:

```
TitleList.find(43).users
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TitleList.includes(:users).find(43)
```

The `where` will bring back an array of one which you could handle with `.first` at the end.

```
TitleList.where(:id => 43).includes(:users).first
```

or similar to what you had:

```
TitleList.includes(:users).where(:id => 43).first
```

I didn't think `all` could take params.  I see an error when I try it.

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```